# Open Workspace edit google cloud (cloud shell) dont work

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

Yesterday I tried to delete folders in the cloud shell editor, being impossible to delete.
This morning I have decided to remove all the files from the main directory:

sudo rm -rf $ HOME

Now I click on the button -> Open workspace and it does nothing.
It also does not receive repositories from GitHub.
Any ideas?.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you deleted all your files from the home folder and now you are unable to use Cloud Shell, please correct me if this is not your situation.

If this is the case you can try to restart your Cloud Shell by pressing in the three dots on the top right corner and select ´Restart´. If this doesn't help you can also try to boot in Safe Mode.

If your problem is selecting a workspace keep in mind that after you used the command ´sudo rm -rf $ HOME´ you most likely deleted your workspace folder that is usually inside of the home dir. You will have to create a new folder and select it as your new workspace in the ´Open Workspace´ menu

Comment: Yes, this is the case. I am  restart me Cloud Shell. Its working. Thanks you¡¡¡ Best regards